# innerHTML Not Changing in Javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a default page which has `bootstrap` `tabs`. When i click one of the tabs the content loads from the relevant `DIV` but when i click the other `tab` it does not replace the other `Div`.

All code below

**Default HTML**

```js
function load_RbCode() {
  document.getElementById("rbCode").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="functionality.html" style="width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available"></object>';
}

function load_HelpModalCode() {
  document.getElementById("helpModalCode").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="help_modal.html" style="width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available"></object>';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="rbCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="load_RbCode()">Rule Builder Code</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="helpModalCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="load_HelpModalCode()">Help Modal</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="rbCode"></div>
  <div id="helpModalCode"></div>
</div>
```

As i said it goes to the correct file and displays.  If i click the 'Help' `tab` first then the 'Rule' `tab` it does replace but i think this is because there is a lot more `HTML` in the 'Rule' file but if i select 'Rule' `tab` first then the 'Rule' `HTML` still displays and it should just be a `button` which launchs a `Modal`

Comment: "the 'Rule' HTML still displays" ....well you have not got any code which would remove it, so yes it will still be there. The other HTML is probably just underneath it. Without some CSS info or a working demo it's hard to be sure.

Comment: P.S. Any particular reason you're using `<object` just to display a HTML file? You could load it into a regular div using AJAX, or use an iframe. `<object` is normally used for multimedia like Flash, or embedding a PDF or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the content of the `div` element which you are not using.

This isn't related to your issue but when you feed the `innerHTML()` method a string of text containing HTML markup it is converted to a DocumentFragment object representing the new DOM nodes for the HTML elements. You can do this yourself in JavaScript and when you bundle the code into a function you have cleaner and more performant code.

```js
function addObjectElement (containerElem, contentUrl) {
  // Create a new `object` element 
  var newElement = document.createElement("object");
  // Set the element attributes
  newElement.setAttribute("type", "text/html");
  newElement.style.cssText = "width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available";
  newElement.setAttribute("data", contentUrl);
  // Clear the container element if it's populated
  if (containerElem.hasChildNodes())
    containerElem.innerHTML = "";
  // Add the new element to the container
  containerElem.appendChild(newElement);
}

function load_RbCode(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Clear `#helpModalCode`
  document.getElementById("helpModalCode").innerHTML = "";
  // Populate `#rbCode`
  addObjectElement(document.getElementById("rbCode"), "functionality.html");
}

function load_HelpModalCode(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Clear `#rbCode`
  document.getElementById("rbCode").innerHTML = "";
  // Populate `#helpModalCode`
  addObjectElement(document.getElementById("helpModalCode"), "help_modal.html");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="rbCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href ="#" onclick="load_RbCode(event)">Rule Builder Code</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="helpModalCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href ="#" onclick="load_HelpModalCode(event)">Help Modal</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="rbCode"></div>
  <div id="helpModalCode"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag

```js
function load_RbCode(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("rbCode").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="functionality.html" style="width: 100%; background:red;height: -100%"></object>';
}

function load_HelpModalCode(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("helpModalCode").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="help_modal.html" style="width: 100%;background:green; height: 100%"></object>';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="rbCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="load_RbCode(event)">Rule Builder Code</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="helpModalCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="load_HelpModalCode(event)">Help Modal</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="rbCode"></div>
  <div id="helpModalCode"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code only displays the information when it is clicked but it does not hide the other tab content (or clear the content) when a tab is clicked.

Edit: same as what was mentioned by ADyson in the comment

```
function load_RbCode() {
    //clear the other tab content
    document.getElementById("helpModalCode").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("rbCode").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="functionality.html" style="width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available"></object>';
}

function load_HelpModalCode() {
    //clear the other tab content
    document.getElementById("rbCode").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("helpModalCode").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="help_modal.html" style="width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available"></object>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code: your option tag is blank.. so its not showing.. when you put some value in it.. your code also show this.

```js
        function load_RbCode() {
            document.getElementById("rbCode").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="functionality.html" style="width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available;background:red;">one</object>';
        }
    
        function load_HelpModalCode() {
            document.getElementById("helpModalCode").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="help_modal.html" style="width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available;background:blue;">two</object>';
        }
```

```html
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="rbCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href ="#" onclick="load_RbCode()">Rule Builder Code</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="helpModalCodeMenu" class="nav-link" href ="#" onclick="load_HelpModalCode()">Help Modal</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="rbCode">text</div>
        <div id="helpModalCode">tst2</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Jquery.

Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
and then 
`$('#rbCode').html('<object type="text/html" data="functionality.html" style="width: 100%; height: -webkit-fill-available"></object>');`

Comment: Implement a complete library to fix one issue is bad advice in my opinion.

Comment: Not only that, the answer doesn't explain what it thinks the issue is, or why this code would fix it. IMO the proposed code wouldn't resolve anything in this case. All it does is pointlessly add a whole new code library to the solution.